# MySQL Server has Gone Away in Drupal 7 Cache

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

In drupal for my menu configuration, i click on edit and this error appears,

> Oct 23 11:43:38 
>   1414057418|php|/structure/menu/item/759/edit|/structure/menu/manage/main-menu|1||PDOException:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away:
>   DELETE FROM {cache} #012WHERE  (cid LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_0
>   ESCAPE '\') ; Array#012(#012
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => entity_info:%#012)#012 in
>   cache_clear_all() (line 165 of
>   /var/www/enerdata.net/includes/cache.inc).

Anybody Know how to rectify this error...

Comment: It's nearly always an insufficiently large `MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET` on the MySQL server config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up your my.ini file, increase the value of MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET, then restart your mysql service.

See the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html).